# Speeding up this code snippet

Tags: python, matlab

I am rewriting one code from Matlab to Python.

Matlab code looks like this:

```
validIntSize = length(prices1)-125; %valid interval size
interval720s = zeros(validIntSize,120+1);
interval360s = zeros(validIntSize,60+1);
interval180s = zeros(validIntSize,30+1);

for i = 1:intJump:validIntSize
    interval180s(i,:) = [prices1(i:i+29),priceDiff(i+29)]; 
    interval360s(i,:) = [prices1(i:i+59),priceDiff(i+59)]; 
    interval720s(i,:) = [prices1(i:i+119),priceDiff(i+119)];  
end
```

It populates the rows of this huge matrix in a nutshell. I do this through append in Python and it takes way too long:

```
 intervals = []
 for mean in self.means: intervals.append([])

 for i in range(stop_point):
     for idx, mean in enumerate(self.means):
          intervals[idx].append(list(prices1[i:(i+mean)])+[price_diff[i+mean]])
```

I suspect that this is due to  the append method that I am using?

P.S. it takes about 2 seconds in Matlab and about 2 minutes in Python.

P.P.S changing my code to list comprehension as suggested in the comments:

```
for idx, k_mean in enumerate(self.k_means):
    intervals[idx] = [list(prices1[i:(i+k_mean)])+[price_diff[i+k_mean]] for i in range(stop_point)]
```

does not speed up the code. Takes virtually the same amount of time.

Comment: If you have working code that you want to improve you should consider to post such questions on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: You don't seem to really need to append anything to intervals. Does a list comprehension improve speed?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre let me try that now.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre nope. Same amount of time. Is it possible to parallelize appending for each mean in self.means?

Comment: You don't need to loop. Here is a vectorized solution in MATLAB/Octave . `ii = (1:intJump:validIntSize).';
interval180s = [prices1(ii+(0:29)) reshape(priceDiff(ii+29),[],1)];` In numpy you can use broadcasting/indexing to get the same result.

Comment: @rahnema1 not very familiar with broadcasting.

Comment: It means adding together two matrices of different sizes. For example add a `[5 x 1]` matrix to a `[5 X 5]` matrix as it has done it the MATLAB code `ii+(0:29)`. Numpy also can do broadcasting . [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) explained.

Comment: @rahnema1 but I don't need to add matrices of different sizes. I just need an array in which I have x number of elements (where x = len(self.means)). Where each element has fixed number of rows = stop_point, but variable number of columns (each mean in self.means)

Comment: You add two matrices to get matrix of  indexes. Then use the matrix of indexes to slice `prices1`.

Comment: @rahnema1 would you be able to write a toy example in the answer?  thanks

Comment: Something like this `import numpy as np;ii = np.arange(0,validIntSize,intJump).reshape(-1,1);interval180s = np.hstack((prices1[ii+np.arange(0,30).reshape(1,-1)] , priceDiff[ii.reshape(1,-1) + 29].reshape(-1,1))`

Comment: @rahnema1 getting a TypeError when I do this: prices1[ii + np.arange(0,2)] (adding reshape(1,-1) results in the same array)

>>
prices1 = [2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30]
priceDiff = np.array(pd.DataFrame(data=prices1).diff())
prices1[ii + np.arange(0,2)]

Comment: got it. it's because prices1 was a list and not np.array. Thanks. I'll check the speed now

Comment: oh but it gives me the incorrect vallues, even though indices are correct

Comment: all is good actually

Comment: super fast. brilliant :) thanks